# Best known asymptotic PCP sizes / 3-SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, pcp

What are the best known asymptotic upper bounds on sizes of probabilistically checkable proofs?  Ideally, I am looking for a contemporary survey on this broad question, but if there is none, I am especially interested in inapproximability of 3-SAT.

Let 7/8+ε-3-SAT be 3-SAT with the promise that if 7/8+ε fraction of the clauses are satisfiable, then the instance is satisfiable.  What are the best known reductions of 3-SAT with $n$ clauses to 7/8+ε-3-SAT?  For example, is there a reduction using $O(n \log n)$ clauses? ($O(n)$ clauses is an open problem.)  A reduction in uniform quasilinear size NC?  What is the dependence on $ε$, including when $ε→0$? Is there a known linear size (dependent on $ε$) reduction of (1-ε)-3-SAT to 7/8+ε-3-SAT, and if not, do we have better bounds for (1-ε)-3-SAT?  Even a partial answer would be interesting.

Also, while it would perhaps make the question too broad, I should mention that another important issue here are the constant factors, which due to techniques like the long code are commonly infeasibly large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The state-of-the-art for PCPs that yield a reduction to $(\frac{7}{8}+\varepsilon)$ 3-SAT (even for sub-constant $\varepsilon$) are [those of Dana Moshkovitz and Ran Raz](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il//eccc-reports/2008/TR08-071/index.html), which have length $n^{1 + o(1)}$. I do not know, however, if anyone tried to compute the exact dependence of the length on $\varepsilon$, or the computation complexity of the reduction. Their main technical result was simplified later [by Irit Dinur and Prahladh Harsha](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/DH.pdf).

If you are interested in short PCPs with a constant number of queries that do not necessarily give optimal hardness-of-approximation reductions (a.k.a. "high-error PCPs"), then the state-of-the-art result is PCPs of length $n\cdot \mathrm{poly}\log n$ due to [Eli Ben-Sasson and Madhu Sudan](http://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/papers/2005/rspcpp-full.pdf) and its improvement by [Dinur](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/combpcp.pdf). Again, I do not know if anyone what is the exact complexity of computing the reduction.

Comment: Thank you; both parts were helpful.  I gather that quasilinear size PCP with O(1) queries and constant error remains an open problem.

Comment: No, that actually follows from the work of Ben-Sasson and Sudan. It is an open problem to get such PCPs with sub-constant error.

Comment: I looked some more and [Dinur 2007](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/combpcp.pdf) extends the paper you cited in the second paragraph to show $SAT ∈ PCP_{\frac{1}{2},1}[\log_2 n + O(\log \log n), O(1)]$.  If I understand correctly, this implies a reduction of 3-SAT to some quasilinear size $1-ε$ 3-SAT, but the result you cited in the first paragraph is nonredundant because it gives us $7/8+ε$ and more.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I forgot to mention Dinur's result, I'll add it to the answer.